# How can I fix the issue with the input string in this cmdlet?

Tags: c#, powershell

In the last month of so I have been trying to learn some C# with the aim of writing some PowerShell modules. I looked at some [articles](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-development/using-c-to-create-powershell-cmdlets-the-basics/) and [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/creating-wmi-clients) (Creating a client with C# - Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure) to try and put together a simple CIM cmdlet that would return the local network adapters.

The class library compiles okay, but when I run the command in PowerShell, it shows a format exception.

```bsh
Show-LocalAdapter : Input string was not in a correct format.
```

In function based problems, I would normally see an issue with a line in the error reporting, but the error does not point me in the right direction with a cmdlet.

Hopefully someone here can help me as I have exhausted my, admittedly limited, knowledge on debugging this problem.

Here is the code for the cmdlet.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure;

namespace NetTest
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Show, "LocalAdapter")]
    [OutputType(typeof(NetworkAdapter))]
    public class ShowLocalAdapterCmdlet : PSCmdlet
    {
        private string[] _manufacturer;
        private string _name;
        private bool? _physicalAdapter;
        private int _maxEntries = 100;

        [Parameter(Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true)]
        [Alias("Vendor")]
        public string[] Manufacturer
        {
            get { return this._manufacturer; }
            set { _manufacturer = value; }
        }

        [Parameter(Position = 1, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true)]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return this._name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }

        [Parameter(Position = 2, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true)]
        public bool? PhysicalAdapter
        {
            get { return this._physicalAdapter; }
            set { _physicalAdapter = value; }
        }

        [Parameter(Position = 3)]
        public int MaxEntries
        {
            get { return this._maxEntries; }
            set { _maxEntries = value; }
        }

        protected override void BeginProcessing()
        {
            base.BeginProcessing();
        }

        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            CimSession session = CimSession.Create("localHost");
            IEnumerable cimResults = session.QueryInstances(@"root\cimv2", "WQL", "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter");
            var query = cimResults.Cast<CimInstance>().Select(ReturnNetworkAdapter);

            // Filter Name
            if (Name != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(adapter => adapter.Name != null && adapter.Name.StartsWith(Name));
            }

            // Manufacturer Filter
            if (Manufacturer != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(
                    adapter =>
                        adapter.Manufacturer != null &&
                        Regex.IsMatch(adapter.Manufacturer.ToString(),
                            string.Format("^(?:{0})", string.Join("|", Manufacturer))));
            }

            // Physical Adapter: true or false
            if (PhysicalAdapter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(adapter =>
                    adapter.PhysicalAdapter == PhysicalAdapter);
            }

            // Return objects
            query.Take(MaxEntries).ToList().ForEach(WriteObject);
        }

        private static NetworkAdapter ReturnNetworkAdapter(CimInstance item)
        {
            return new NetworkAdapter
            {
                Name            = item.CimInstanceProperties["Name"].ToString(),
                Description     = item.CimInstanceProperties["Description"].ToString(),
                DeviceId        = int.Parse(item.CimInstanceProperties["DeviceId"].ToString()),
                Manufacturer    = item.CimInstanceProperties["Manufacturer"].ToString(),
                NetConnectionId = item.CimInstanceProperties["NetConnectionId"].ToString(),
                PhysicalAdapter = bool.Parse(item.CimInstanceProperties["PhysicalAdapter"].ToString())
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the class for the network adapter object.

```cs
namespace NetTest
{
    public class NetworkAdapter
    {
        private string _name;
        private string _description;
        private int _deviceId;
        private string _manufacturer;
        private string _netConnectionId;
        private bool _physicalAdapter;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }
        public string Description
        {
            get { return _description; }
            set { _description = value; }
        }
        public int DeviceId
        {
            get { return _deviceId; }
            set { _deviceId = value; }
        }
        public string Manufacturer
        {
            get { return _manufacturer; }
            set { _manufacturer = value; }
        }
        public string NetConnectionId
        {
            get { return _netConnectionId; }
            set { _netConnectionId = value; }
        }
        public bool PhysicalAdapter
        {
            get { return _physicalAdapter; }
            set { _physicalAdapter = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your efforts to write a cmdlet. Will this provide more than `Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_NetworkAdapter` provides?

Comment: The end result or the cmdlet itself isn't as important as the learning opportunity. I am a lot more familiar with PowerShell and thus know the cmdlet you are referring to.

Comment: This error could be caused by the `int.Parse` statement: `[int]::Parse("x")` ->
`Exception calling "Parse" with "1" argument(s): "Input string was not in a correct format."`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calls like this `item.CimInstanceProperties["Name"].ToString()` is not what are you expecting. You should look at property `Value`:

```
private static NetworkAdapter ReturnNetworkAdapter(CimInstance item)
{
    return new NetworkAdapter
    {
        Name = item.CimInstanceProperties["Name"].Value.ToString(),
        Description = item.CimInstanceProperties["Description"].Value?.ToString(),
        DeviceId = int.Parse(item.CimInstanceProperties["DeviceId"].Value.ToString()),
        Manufacturer = item.CimInstanceProperties["Manufacturer"].Value?.ToString(),
        NetConnectionId = item.CimInstanceProperties["NetConnectionId"].Value?.ToString(),
        PhysicalAdapter = bool.Parse(item.CimInstanceProperties["PhysicalAdapter"].Value.ToString())
    };
}
```

Comment: Hi Zergatul, thanks for the answer, I will try this out today. Is the '?' an operator that is checking the value first? Sorry for the newbie questions.

Comment: @Ash `?.`  operator checks for null first, and then calls method or property